# Tomcat for http://localhost:8080/ is OK, but for http://localhost:8080/app/index.html shows HTTP Status 404

Tags: http, tomcat, http-status-code-404, status

I've got a weird issue.

After startup Tomcat manually on Win 10 http://localhost:8080/ can be shown with no problems.

Now in both webapps and webapps/test directories there is a file index.html.

And the access to
http://localhost:8080/app/index.html or
to
http://localhost:8080/index.html

shows HTTP Status 404

with followings:

Type Status Report
Message The requested resource [/index] is not available
Beschreibung The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Please, can someone help? Thanks!